# scipy dll's not found by executable made with pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, pyinstaller, exe

I'm trying to make an executeable out of my python script with pyinstaller in Windows (10). The pyinstaller process goes down without any problems, but when I launch the .exe, any time the program reaches a step where it needs to use anything from scipy, it crashes without an error message - if there is no anaconda installed for the user. If anaconda is there, there are no problems (but I can't make the future users of the program install anaconda). I theorize from looking up this question that the issue is that the .exe can't find the .dll's necessary to use these scipy modules, but I don't know how to add them to the .exe (I tried with hiddenimports, I tried adding the `anaconda3\myenv\Lib\site-packages` folder to the path where pyinstaller looks for these things). I found some solutions that pointed me towards that I should find an `extra-dll` folder somewhere and include that in the .spec file, but it seems to be missing for me.

minimum reproducible code with the same issue (basically copied from the curve_fit documentation):

```
import scipy.optimize as opt
import numpy as np

def func(x, a, b, c):

    return a * np.exp(-b * x) + c

xdata = np.linspace(0, 4, 50)

y = func(xdata, 2.5, 1.3, 0.5)

y_noise = np.random.normal(0,1,50)

ydata = y + y_noise

popt, pcov = opt.curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)

print(popt)
```

python 2.7 (yes, I know, but I'm stuck with it), anaconda latest version, pyinstaller 3.5, scipy 1.2.1

Answer (score 0):

for in case anyone ever ends up here with the same problem: the answer is not using Anaconda.

the problem persisted on Python 3.9 in Anaconda as well, turns it out it's because the current Anaconda (individual edition 2021.11. as far as I'm aware) downloads unstable 5.x.x.dev version of pyinstaller which doesn't cooperate well with scipy (and downgrading within Anaconda didn't fix the issue). What fixed it was getting rid of Anaconda and getting plain old Python 3.10 (presumably works with 2.7.17 as well) and installing the necessary packages with pip. (and meanwhile I forgot the login credentials to my old account)

Comment: But isn't the whole point of using pyInstaller is creating a stand-alone exe? What is the point if I would have to install packages with pip? I want to be able to run the exe in a computer that doens't even have python installed.

Comment: Maybe my comment wasn't entirely clear, installing those packages with pip is only necessary to make the exe, afterwards it can be distributed without needing to install python